# JavaScript array not recognized

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem.

I have the following JavaScript array created:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      ArrayName['FirstValue']['SecondValue'] = {
       name = 'checbox_id'
       checked = true }
    </script>
```

But when I call the Global Array in a function here is a sample call:

```
    ArrayName[value1][value2] = true;
```

I'm getting a messaging stating that ArrayName is undefined.

What would a correct way to create an array similar to the one above?

Comment: Well, where *is* `ArrayName` defined?

Comment: Let's start with, "Why do you want a global array?"

Comment: Cause I want to use it again...

Comment: There's no multi-dimensional arrays in JS. You can emulate them with nested arrays, but then you've to define the arrays one by one. Also, it  looks like you'd need [an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) instead of an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to set an element in an array called `ArrayName`, which is not declared anywhere:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // You are attempting to access an array but it hasn't been declared:
   ArrayName['FirstValue']['SecondValue'] = {
   name = 'checbox_id'
   checked = true }
</script>
```

Your syntax indicates that this is an array that contains nested arrays, like this:

```
var ArrayName = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
```

So, if you wanted to get the number 8, you'd need to access the third array element and get the second value found in the array stored there with this syntax:

```
// Remember, array indexes start counting from zero
ArrayName[2][1];  // Get the third element's, second item
```

Or (if we take your example literally, where you are searching for literal strings that are not positive integers), `ArrayName` wouldn't be an array, it would be an Object that you are trying to access the property `FirstValue` of and this property then stores another object as its value and that object has a property called `SecondValue`.  That structure would look like this:

```
var myObjectLiteral = {
  FirstValue : { SecondValue : something }
}
```

But, without knowing what you are trying to accomplish, we can't possibly help you write the array or the object.

Next, we have to talk about the object that you are trying to assign to the array:

```
{
       name = 'checbox_id'
       checked = true
}
```

This syntax is incorrect. You are missing a comma to separate on key/value pair from the next. It should be:

```
{
       name : 'checbox_id',
       checked : true
}
```

Comment: `ArrayName = ['FirstValue']['SecondValue'] = {};` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Since the code is actually: `ArrayName['FirstValue']['SecondValue'] = {
 name = 'checbox_id'  checked = true }` I think it does.